# Get result of async function in sync function

Tags: swift, async-await, vapor

How can I convert this code to `async await`?

```swift
func syncFunction() -> String {
    let result: String = try myEventLoopFutureWithResult.wait()
    return result
}
```

I have tried this approach so far, but I cannot get the result of the operation and it doesn't block (but I want it to block):

```swift
func syncFunction() -> String {
    Task {
        try await myAsyncFunctionWithResult()
    }

    // missing return of async function ...
}
```

I found this, which seems to block, but I cannot get the result of my `async` function:

```swift
func syncFunction() -> String {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    Task(priority: priority) {
        defer { semaphore.signal() }
        return try await myAsyncFunctionWithResult()
    }
    
    semaphore.wait()

    // missing return of async function ...
}
```

The last approach I found was this, which I think works but is kind of complicated for how simple the problem is (I think):

```swift
func syncFunction(eventLoop: EventLoop) -> String {
    let promise = eventLoop.makePromise(of: String.self)
    promise.completeWithTask {
        try await myAsyncFunctionWithResult()
    }
    return try promise.futureResult.wait()
}
```

TLDR: I want to call an `async` function in a sync function by blocking and getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

ok the use case to do this was to call an async function from an Vapor `Command` but it's better to use an `AsyncCommand` instead so i can make everything async instead

Comment: Can you post your final code?

Comment: the documentation of vapor recommends them: https://docs.vapor.codes/advanced/commands/